# resource folder not detecting in my integration (it) folder

Tags: java, spring, maven, resources, integration-testing

I have created a maven project to with separate folder for keeping the integration test cases, the configuration I have done is through maven and it is working fine. But the project is even though I have mentioned the resources folder location in maven using the configuration like as shown below, still it is not detecting

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-it-resources</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/it-classes</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I have created a small test case (**TestmodulesApplicationIT.java**) under the **it** folder to check the resource folder properties like as shown below

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestmodulesApplication.class)
class TestmodulesApplicationIT {

    @Value("${name:}")
    public String name;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertTrue("manu".equals(name));
    }
}
```

The above test fails since it is not able to detect the resource folder

You can see the full source code over https://github.com/alexman31/testmodules

Can someone please help me on this

Comment: Why using a `src/it/..` ? why not putting your integration test into `src/test/java`... ?

Comment: We want to separate our integration tests from unit test, it was a requirement given to me. Everything works fine except the resources folder

Comment: Based on the naming convention they are separated.

Comment: @khmarbaise I have done this examples based on your examples given for externalizing separate integration folder. It works really nice but only the resources are not detecting

Comment: On which examples?

Comment: @khmarbaise I didn’t get that....based on which naming convention

Comment: @khmarbaise this is from where I got this configuration - https://github.com/khmarbaise/maui/issues/2

Comment: The naming convention for unit test mean named like `*Test.java` ( https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) and integration test run via failsafe-plugin named like `*IT.java` see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes that's easiest and best separated IT's are usually only needed if you need different dependencies but than you have to use a separate module not separate directory...

Comment: @khmarbaise like to know  why you suggest not to create a separate folder for integration test. Having a separate folder for integration test will be much cleaner way to separate from unit tests right

Comment: Why do you need a separate folder for your integration tests? Do they have different dependencies or something like this? Yes you have to go via separate module if not you can keep them into the same module... The separation is the naming convention. clean and simple... But go for what you like...

Comment: @khmarbaise at the moment the integration does not have any different dependencies, but separating it into a different folder makes it clean and easy to maintain it for developers, otherwise the test folder would rather be a mess of unit and integration test

Comment: If you just use a separate package it would be much more easier and not any supplemental configuration of any plugin except the failsafe plugin would be needed...

Comment: @khmarbaise, ok got it. Also alternatively how about creating folders under test folder like as shown  here https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwj8t.png, Is it possible using maven or gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced a similar scenario, some years later but I hope it help others, basically I also added an `it` folder to have integration tests there and I am also using `failsafe` plugin to run them, in order to make your configuration file visible for tests it is needed to have it under `target/test-classes` folder before running tests, so I added this in my pom.xml

```
<build>
    ....
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>
                ${project.basedir}/src/it/resources
            </directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    ....
</build>
```

This will add your properties file to mentioned folder, so you can configure a class to read it:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Value("${name:}")
    public String name;

    ... getters

}
```

and use it on your tests, for example:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(
    classes = TestConfig.class, 
    initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class
)
public class TestApplicationIT {

    @Autowired
    private TestConfig testConfig;

    .... your tests

}
```